# Jira filter to show jiras that have subtask

Tags: jira, jira-filter

I know there is a way to show jiras that are subtasks and jiras that are not subtask. But I didn't find a way to show jiras that have subtasks. Somebody know if there is a filter for this.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using ScriptRunner you can create a filter using this JQL:

```
issueFunction in hasSubtasks()
```

ScriptRunnner is no longer free as of version 4, but you can still download older versions:

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/versions